# VB.NET Send strings between applications?

Tags: vb.net, string, client, ipc, send

I have two VB.NET apps. One will run as an administrator, and the other one will act as a 'receiver/client'. Anyway, the receiver just sits in the tray, so it has no HWND, so I could not use Postmessage or sendmessage to communicate with it. Is there a way to send strings between processes with VB.NET without the HWND or either application?

Comment: The tray application will still have a Hwnd

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into the TcpClient class you can use this as both server and client. There is an example on the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx).

Here is a more complex example project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/307315/Reusable-multithreaded-tcp-client-and-server-class

Comment: OK, I got the HWND now. I made a window. Anyway, how do I use postmessage to send strings across processes?

Comment: I gave you an alternative to using postmessage as requested. If you now want to use postmessage that is another question

Comment: What do you think about using files for communication, such as writing to a file and reading from it?

Comment: Files are a really bad idea because there are so many possible points of failure.